How to Override a Package's __init__.py Without Breaking Submodule Imports in Python?
I'm working on a project where I need to override files located in the ./lib/python3.9/site-packages" directory. I have the following hook that does just that using importlib.util and sys.meta_path.insert:

The Override files is in ./lib_changes/*.

The Hook does work in all of the following files except the zope+intid.__init__.py file



import re
import sys
import importlib.util
import os
from Zope2.Startup.serve import main
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger("RunWSGI")

def generate_override_mapping(lib_changes_dir):
    override_mapping = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(lib_changes_dir):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            module_name = filename[:-3].replace("+", ".")
            # Special handling for __init__.py files
            if module_name.endswith(".__init__"):
                module_name = module_name[:-9]
            override_mapping[module_name] = os.path.join(lib_changes_dir, filename)
    return override_mapping

class CustomImportHook:
    def __init__(self, override_mapping):
        self.override_mapping = override_mapping
        self.override_counter = 0

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path=None, target=None):
        
        if fullname in self.override_mapping:
            override_path = self.override_mapping[fullname]
            LOGGER.info(f"{fullname} Overide by {override_path}")
            self.override_counter += 1

            return importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(fullname, override_path)

        return None


lib_changes_dir = '/opt/projects/Plone/site/backend/lib_changes'
override_mapping = generate_override_mapping(lib_changes_dir)

sys.meta_path.insert(0, CustomImportHook(override_mapping))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())

Problem: I'm trying to override zope.intid.__init__.py (or any .__init__.py file) with a custom implementation located in a different directory. However, I'm encountering an issue where the package submodules are not recognized correctly, leading to ModuleNotFoundError errors. For example, once the Hook successfully replaced the implementation of zope.intid.__init__.py with the one located at ./lib_changes, improts such as import zope.intid.interfaces is not longer working (err: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zope.intid.interfaces'; 'zope.intid' is not a package.
Question: How can I properly override the __init__.py of the zope.intid package (or any .__init__.py package file) without breaking the import of its submodules? Is there a way to correctly set up the custom import hook to handle this scenario?

Your method of overriding imports will effectively "shadow" over whatever subpackages that are provided underneath (evident by zope.intid works but zope.intid.interfaces failing after your patch). You may need to employ monkey patching instead rather than overriding the import mechanism as the result of that will override whatever existing module that was resolved by the "standard" import.

Or alternatively, ensure that your patched module will have a way to fall back to the original location should the patched imports are not resolved to a patched location (i.e. zope.intid.interfaces will be imported from the original location through the patched module, whereas it's "blocked" now because it doesn't have a way to resolve it).

Correct, tried both approaches and both work - incase of the fall back, it turns out that spec_from_file_location function have submodule_search_locations param that does just that. Thanks

Nice, please considering putting in a self answer, the submodule_search_locations argument probably will be of most use for future readers.

It turns out I was on the right track. Thanks to @metatoaster, the problem I was having was due to the patched module had no way to fall back into the default module location incase of import resolution issue. The key is too provide set of other paths to try via submodule_search_locations of the
spec_from_file_location function:
..
class CustomImportHook:
def __init__(self, override_mapping):
    self.override_mapping = override_mapping
    self.override_counter = 0

def find_spec(self, fullname, path=None, target=None):

    if fullname in self.override_mapping:
        override_path = self.override_mapping[fullname]
        LOGGER.info(f"{fullname} Overide by {override_path}")
        self.override_counter += 1
                    
        return importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
            fullname, 
            override_path,
            submodule_search_locations = [f'/../lib/python3.9/site-packages/<path-to-default-package']
        )

    return None
..

